# How to display output like this in SQL?

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sql-server-2014, tabular

I have a table like the one shown below:

```
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Name           | Model | system   | ItemTag |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Alarm Id       | T58   | ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Door Lock      | F48   | ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| AlarmSounder   | T58   | ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Card Reader    | K12   | ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Magnetic Lock  | F48   | ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| T2 Card Reader | K12   | ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Power   Supply | Null  | ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Battery         |  Null| ASC      |         |
+----------------+-------+----------+---------+
```

Now I want to display the data  like this:

```
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| Name        | Model | system | count  |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| Alarm       | T58   | ASC    | 2      |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| Door Lock   | F58   | ASC    | 2      |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| Card Reader | K12   | ASC    | 2      |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
|Power supply | Null   | ASC    | 1     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
| Battery    | Null   | ASC    | 1     |
+-------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

How to do it in SQL?

Updated 
I also included null column as my second update.

Comment: What's the logic? Why does `AlarmSounder`, `Magnetic Lock` and `T2 Card Reader` are not in the output?

Comment: @ZoharPeled ,updated the question

Comment: Still doesn't help. How can you tell the difference between rows you want to return and rows you don't want to return?

Comment: Why ( 'Alarm Id'  , 'AlarmSounder') => 'Alarm' but ('Door Lock', 'Magnetic Lock') => 'Door Lock' ?

Comment: @Serg ,  This from our  purchase team and they stored data like this

Comment: I see, but the question is about the query. What is the rule which transforms `name` as it is shown in the question?

Comment: If you want ' Alarm  Id' in the output realy, please edit your question.

Comment: @serg , Alarm  is fine for but i want to return maximum matching rows  from similar  strings

Comment: This is my question exactly , what is the rule of extracting ' maximum matching'  from a set of names? Why ('Door Lock', 'Magnetic Lock') => 'Door Lock' for example ? It doesn't look like extracting the matching part.

Comment: This has lot to do with the spare parts  of the devices. So our procurement team is following this model for their records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use windowed functions:

```
SELECT Name, Model, system, cnt AS count 
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Model) AS cnt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY ...) AS rn
      FROM your_tab) AS sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/OYIP88302)**

Keep in mind that you need a column to sort so (id/timestamp) should be used to get first value in a group.

---

**EDIT:**

> As i have different Name relating to null column. how can i seperate it out

```
SELECT Name, Model, system, cnt AS count 
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Model) AS cnt,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY id) AS rn
      FROM my_tab
      WHERE Model IS NOT NULL) AS sub
WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Model, system, 1
FROM my_tab
WHERE Model IS NULL;
```

**[RextesterDemo 2](http://rextester.com/EPOB65523)**

Comment: this is almost perfect.. All  the rows are returing with the total  But i have issues in null  column . As i have different Name relating to null column. how can i seperate it out

Comment: @aryan Now you are extending your question. I suggest to ask new question with sample data and result. You could use my http://rextester.com to provide all necessary data.

Comment: @aryan: You need to include all scenarios in question because we try to construct query based on data provided in question. There is no nulls in your sample data.

Comment: @lad2025 ,  Updated

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple query as below

```
SELECT MIN(Name) Name, 
       Model, 
       system, 
       COUNT(*) [count]
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY Model, system
```

Result

```
Name        Model   system  count
Door Lock   F58     ASC     2
Card Reader K12     ASC     2
Alarm Id    T58     ASC     2
```

Answer (score 1):

lad2025's solution simplified, calculate both NULL and NOT NULL in a single step and add some logic for the NULL rows:

```
SELECT Name, Model, system, 
   CASE WHEN Model IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE cnt END AS count 
FROM
 (
   SELECT *, 
      COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Model) AS cnt,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Model ORDER BY Name) AS rn
   FROM my_tab
 ) AS sub
WHERE rn = 1         -- one row per model 
   OR Model IS NULL; -- all rows for the NULL model
```

Comment: i didnt get the case statement part ..0CASE WHEN Model IS NULL THEN 1  Its saying when model is null then 1 ,which  one its pointing here.

Comment: @aryan: This simply replaces the count of the NULL rows with 1 to match your expected result :-)

Comment: yes. i replaced the case with not null and saw what it actually doing in  the query.  thanks for that  .